# react big calendar display timezone

Tags: reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

I want to display the time zone in the calendar edge, it will be like that:
[image]

GMT+x, do you have any idea if that's possible?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, you would want the latest (0.36.0) version of RBC, which includes timezone support when using the `momentLocalizer` of the new `luxonLocalizer`. Second, you cannot currently override the internal `TimeGutter` component. You would have to replicate all of the views that use `TimeGrid` and copy over code to write that in yourself.